# IIS 7 and PHP 5.3 or PHP 7 - how to add MySQLlibary

Tags: php, mysql, iis-7

How to install MySQL libary to IIS 7 PHP 5.3 or PHP 7?
My server: Windows Server 2016

I need MySQL to connect very old code... ;)

Comment: But MySQL won't connect anywhere? If anything you would be running very old PHP code. In Which case you should check whenever part of it isn't deprecated, especially if you're using PHP 7. Also consider (if it's your code) to change it to use `mysqli`. Lookup how to load/configure the used extensions in order to configure it for your PHP installation.

Comment: but, I want use mysql connection

Comment: mayber or ... I use default IIS websiste, and X website folder. How set THIS FOLDER use PHP 5.3 ? anywhere use defautlt PHP 7..?